# Issue Faced while deleting user record using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url-routing

**Scenario:**

I have used AJAX to delete the record and PHP as the programming language. The AJAX part is given below:

Here `$('#id')` is the `id` of the button which contains the value of **user's id** from the database dynamically with the help of this part: `id='.$d['ID'].'` implemented in the front end.

```
<script>
    function deleteRecord() {
        var var1 = $('#id').html();    
        var result = confirm("Do you want to delete this Record?");
        if(result){
            //call ajax
             $.ajax({
                 url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Device/delete', 
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {
                 id: var1
                 },     
                 success: function(result){
                 $("#id").html(result);
                 alert('You have successfully deleted the user.');
                 },
                 error(e){
                 alert('Problem while interacting to the server.');
                 }
             });
            }
        else{
            console.log('Operation Cancelled.');
        }
    }
    </script>
```

This is the front end part where Button is used to delete the records.
I have used `id='.$d['ID'].'` to get the value of the id dynamically from the database.

```
<td> <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="deleteRecord()" id='.$d['ID'].'>Delete 
</button> </td>
```

This is the url as mentioned in the AJAX:

```
url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Device/delete'
```

In the above URL, **Device** is the name of the **Controller** and **delete** is the method of the **controller** which is given below:

```
public function delete($id = '') {
    $login = $_SESSION['username'];
    if (! in_array($login, $this->main_model->get_authorized_users())) {
        $redirect = site_url('device');
        redirect($redirect, 'refresh');
    }
    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $deviceid = $this->input->post('deviceid');
        if ($deviceid == null || $username == null || $login == null) {
            $redirect = site_url('device');
            redirect($redirect, 'refresh');
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if ($id == '') {
            $redirect = site_url('device');
            redirect($redirect, 'refresh');
        }
        $res = $this->device_model->delete();
        $data['action'] = 'delete';
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $data['result'] = $this->device_model->get_device($id);
        $data['body'] = $this->load->view('register_view', $data, true);
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
}
```

Here is the Model part:

```
function delete(){
    $username = $this->input->get('username');
    $deviceid = $this->input->get('deviceid');
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $language= $this->input->get('language');
    $deleted_by=$_SESSION['username'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM devices
    WHERE id = $id";
    $query = $this->db->query ( $sql );
    //log update
    $this->log_device_delete($id,$username,$deviceid,$deleted_by);
}
```

**Current Output:**

1. When **DELETE** button is pressed then **Confirmation Box** is displayed.
2. In **Confirmation Box**, "**Do you want to delete this Record?**" is asked.

**Issue Faced:**

When user presses the **OK** button then the message called "**You have successfully deleted the user.**" is displayed **but the record is not deleted**.

**Required Solution:**

When the user presses the **OK** button on the Confirmation Box then the user record should be deleted.

**What correction do I need here?**

*Suggestions are highly appreciated.*

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Is the AJAX call built successfully? Is it transfered to the backend successfully, such that the backend receives the expected data? Is there any error on executing the SQL query?

Comment: The AJAX call is successful. It is returning id of the respective users.

Comment: So, what have you tried further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$d['ID']` in `id` attribute. But it need to be placed as value in some field.

The code that you need to update is:

```
<td> 
    <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="deleteRecord(this)" data-id="<?php echo $d['ID']; ?>">Delete</button>
</td>
```

And update in JS as:

```
function deleteRecord(e) {
    var var1 = $(e).data("id");
```

Comment: Should I make any changes in AJAX and javascript as well regarding with the update that you have mentioned?

Comment: I have slightly changed in the AJAX part to check whether the id is being fetched from the form or not. But with this I am getting the id of the first element only while clicking on the any other element.                                                       var var1 = $('#id').val();   
 console.log(var1); 
 return;

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. But I couldn't understand how the data is being fetched from data-id from upper part to var1 in the Javascript part at second part? Can you please provide some explanation?

Comment: This is function in jQuery to fetch data attribute. More details here: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Now I am getting the id on the basis of the user but when I click OK button then the DELETE button gets disappeared instead of deleting the users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173969/discussion-between-lovepreet-singh-and-dixonch).

Answer (score 0):

Try data attribute as

```
<td> <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="deleteRecord()" data-id=".$d['ID'].">Delete 
</button> </td>
```

And in deleteRecord function get that value as

```
   var var1 = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure in the SQL Query you put the right ID?

You said:

> When user presses the OK button then the message called "You have successfully deleted the user." is displayed but the record is not deleted.

You have no errors and AJAX calls the success function. All force me to think about ID problem.

Comment: There is right ID in the SQL query. I have tested the SQL query in the SQL Developer with the successful result.